# node js Complete javascript object not showing in terminal and console

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've been slowly inching towards a solution to an example project for an online course.  In my last question, my major problem was that after I submitted a form, I got two javascript objects returned in the body of the HTML:

```
{"animal":"lion","fact":"a lion's roar can be heard five miles away","fav":""}{"fav":"lions are big"}
```

Now I get the complete object:

```
{"animal":"lion","fact":"a lion's roar can be heard five miles away","fav":"lions are big"}
```

The major problem I'm having now is that I do not see the javascript object in the console or the terminal.  Also, I want the page to stay on the page with the form after I submit it.  Currently, the form is replaced with the javascript object in the body.  I'm trying to get it so when I submit the form I only see the object returned in the console and the terminal but the page stays the same.  I think there may be a problem with my routes but I'm not sure.

The only time I see anything in the console and terminal is when I first open index.html.  When I open the page I get this in the terminal:

```
{
  animal: 'lion',
  fact: "a lion's roar can be heard five miles away",
  fav: {}
}
```

This is my code:

server.js:

```
projectData = {};

/* Express to run server and routes */
const express = require('express');

/* Start up an instance of app */
const app = express();

/* Dependencies */
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
/* Middleware*/
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());

/* Initialize the main project folder*/
app.use(express.static('project1'));

const port = 8000;
/* Spin up the server*/
const server = app.listen(port, listening);
 function listening(){
    // console.log(server);
    console.log(`running on localhost: ${port}`);
  };

// GET route

let animalData = {};
const fakeData = {animal: "lion", fact: "a lion's roar can be heard five miles away"};

app.get('/fakeAnimalData', getFakeData);

function getFakeData(req, res) {
  console.log(fakeData);
  res.send(fakeData);
};

app.get('/all', getData);

function getData(req, res){
  res.send(animalData)
  console.log(animalData)
}

// function sendData (request, response) {
//  response.send(projectData);
// };

// POST route
app.post('/add', callBack);

function callBack(req,res){
  res.send('POST received');
}



// POST an animal
const data = [];


  // TODO-Call Function

app.post('/addAnimal', addAnimal);

app.route('/')
  .get(function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', {root: 'project1'})
  })
  .post(addAnimal);

//app.route('/addAnimal')
//  .get(function (req, res) {
//    res.sendFile('index.html', {root: 'project1'})
//  })
//  .post(addAnimal)

function addAnimal(req, res){
  console.log(req.body);
  Object.assign(animalData, req.body);
  animalData = { ...animalData, ...req.body};
  console.log(animalData);
  res.status(200).send(animalData);

  //newEntry = {
  //  animal: req.body.animal,
  //  fact: req.body.fact,
  //  fav: req.body.fav
  //}

  //data.push(req.body);
//  res.status(200).send(req.body);
  //animalData.push(newEntry)
  // console.log(animalData)
  //console.log(animalData)
};
```

app.js:

```
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', performAction);

function performAction(e){

getAnimal('/fakeAnimalData')
.then(async function(data){
  console.log(data);
  let res = await postData('/', {animal: data.animal, fact: data.fact, fav: fav});
  console.log(res);
});
};

const getAnimal = async (url) =>{
  const res = await fetch(url);
  try {
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data)
    return data;
  } catch(error) {
    console.log()
  }
};

/* Function to POST data */
const postData = async ( url = '', data = {})=>{
    console.log(data);
    let response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
      credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data), // body data type must match "Content-Type" header        
    });
    try {
      const newData = await response.json();
      console.log(newData);
        // console.log(newData);
      return newData
      console.log(await response.json());
      return await response.json()
      }catch(error) {
      console.log("error", error);
      // appropriately handle the error
      };
  };

  // TODO-Call Function
getAnimal('/fakeAnimalData')
.then(async function(data){
    console.log(data);
  let res = await postData('/', {animal: data.animal, fact: data.fact, fav: fav});
  console.log(res);
});
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>What is your favorite thing about this animal?</h2>
        <form action="#" method = "post">
            <textarea id="fav" name="fav" required cols="80" rows="5"></textarea>
            <button type="submit" id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

If you can help me grt the object to show in the console and the terminal while staying on index.html I would appreciate it SO much.

Thanks alot,
Mike

Comment: Did you check if when you do the request "/fakeAnimalData" on browser, the response payload are returned?

Comment: i m not clear about your question ,
one thing for console is not showing 
in your getData method you have used console.log after res.send() that is not correct

Comment: when I request /fakeAnimalData the object is returned in the console and the terminal when I first visit the page.  When I submit the form the incomplete object (only the elements from /fakeAnimalData) is returned.  However, the complete object is returned in the body of the HTML.  The terminal only shows the incomplete object while the body of the HTML returns the complete object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **The only one reason** why you never get your `fav` data in your `console` and `terminal`, it's because you never send `textarea` value. I mean, you send, `textarea` object.

To solve your problem, you can see and use this code below.

**app.js** In your `app.js`, you can change your function `postData` with this code below:

```js
const postData = async ( url = '', data = {})=>{
    const { animal, fact } = data;
    // get your textarea value
    const fav = data.fav.value;
    let response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
      credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ animal, fact, fav}), // body data type must match "Content-Type" header        
    });
    try {
      const newData = await response.json();
      // log the result
      console.log(newData);
      return newData
      }catch(error) {
      console.log("error", error);
      // appropriately handle the error
      };
  };
```

After you change your `postData` with the code above , now you have to change your `index.html`.

**index.html:** You can change your `index.html` with this code below:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Some description</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>What is your favorite thing about this animal?</h2>
        <form>
            <textarea id="fav" name="fav" required cols="80" rows="5"></textarea>
            <button type="button" id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

> The code above only make your page not reload when you click the submit button.

‍ So, now **you can try you app** and I hope it's working.

I hope it can help you .

Comment: thanks ALOT!  I got it to work.  I had to change:

```
const fav = data.fav.value;
```

to:

```
const fav = document.getElementById('fav').value;
```

and now it works exactly like I want it to

Answer (score 0):

now i have the complete object showing up in the terminal.  I had to change this line:

```
  let res = await postData('/', {animal: data.animal, fact: data.fact, fav: fav});
```

to this:

```
  let res = await postData('/', {animal: data.animal, fact: data.fact, fav: req.body});
```